# Eclipse returning exit code=13

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I installed eclipse neon in my win10(64 bit) PC but that was not opening. I reinstalled it. Unfortunately that also, next day it was not opening. so  i deleted all the metadata files. and also uninstalled java 8 version and reinstalled java 7. Now when i am opening eclipse it is throwing msg as "Cannot create virtual machine". I am new to it. so don't have much knowledge.It is returning exit code=1.Please guide.
Now installed java 8 again. bit it is returning code=13

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\ADMIN\.p2\pool\plugin\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Comment: Eclipse Neon **requires** Java 8. Either the reinstalled Java 8 has issues, or your Exit Code 13 has exactly the same cause as so many duplicates. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198527/

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.